# How to record location data in smartstore for syncUp for server

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk

we are developing mobilesdk-ios app in swift using version 7.2 of the sdk.  When the user performs certain actions, we would like to record the current location.  Since the device may be offline, we would like to record the data in the smartstore and then perform syncUp using smartSync.  Does anyone know what data type the soup field should be defined as, and in what format the data should be recorded?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a chance to work on this some more today and I believe I found the solution.

1. Checked the API for the object in SFDC and found that the there are two fields that house the location information.  The two fields have the same name as the field that was created in SFDC, but end in latitude__s and longitude__s (note that it is __s not __c).
2. Added the two fields to the soup as type floating.
3. Added the fields to the syncUp and syncDown and was able to successfully transfer the location data between the mobile sdk app and SFDC.

Hope this helps!